# one to many relations between 3 tables with entity code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Lets say I have 3 tables such as cities, tours and tourdetails

I want to store data about cities which are included in tour and duration of visit for each city. each tour might have several cities.

here is my code

```
public class TourDetails 
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Tour TourID { get; set; }
}

public class Tour
{
    [Required, Key, MaxLength(5), MinLength(5)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string TourName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TotalDuration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<TourDetails> TourDetails { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<TourDetails> TourDetails { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that when I compile code Entity Framework doesn't shows me TourDetails table in diagram at all (table are being added to base) 
I'm pretty new to Entity Framewrok and just trying to learn so it might be a silly question but I hope I will get a proper answer.

---

Issue is solved, problem was with my sql manager studio not with code, thanks a lot who tried to help and sorry for your time :)

Comment: What diagram are you talking about?

Comment: database diagram in sql manager studio which shows relations between tables

Comment: Tried your model and foreign key relationships were created. Everything looks good (except the `Tour TourID` property name, but it's irrelevant).

Comment: Yeah just restarted sql manager studio and it worked for me as well, guess problem was with it not with code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking ids of the entities (and one of properties' name is wrong):

```
public int CityId { get; set;}
public virtual City City { get; set; }
public int TourId { get; set; }
public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework should now detect the relationship

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have ids they're just called simply ID instead of Cityid also tour ID is string could this be an issue? and I fixed last name but that alone didn't help :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that `string` there, my bad. In this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983524/how-to-use-string-property-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework), the answer says, you have to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` for a `string` primary key. Tell if this helps

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help but thanks for the useful info anyway