# SQL Server - Concatenated string sequence as primary key - Insertion fail via EF code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using SQL-Server 2016 and Entity Framework Core.

Let's say we want to use a concatenated string to a sequence as a primary key of a table.
I have created the table using Code-First migration successfully, and have set the default value of the column to be the desired concat (Screenshot from SSMS): 
[image]

When I insert rows to the table manually using the INSERT command, it works as expected. If I choose to omit the value of the column, it is generated from the sequence, otherwise - it uses the value provided.

However, when I try to insert entities by code - an exception is being thrown

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to create or track an entity of type 'EntityName' because it has a null primary or alternate key value.'

The relevant field of the entity is a simple string property. I tried adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` annotation, but that didn't help.

EDIT : When I call `Add (Sync)` stack trace -

```
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityStates(IEnumerable`1 entities, EntityState entityState)
```

When I call `AddAsync` stack trace -

```
Result StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityStates(IEnumerable`1 entities, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable`1 entities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable`1 entities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at (Rest of the stack trace...)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: How are you adding it? I mean are you using `db.Entity.Add` or `db.Entity.AddAsync`? `AddAsync` is required "... to allow special value generators, such as the one used by "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo',to access the database asynchronously."

Comment: I use `DBContext.Entity.AddRange`, not async.

Comment: Try using the `AddRangeAsync` variant and see if that works better, since it should use server-sided value generators. See the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1#methods_

Comment: I had to use the non-async because it was a test class, and I called this method in the constructor to prevent duplication of code across all test methods. Either way - I tried extracting it and call async, didn't work - same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Computed` is what you want - Computed means that the value isn't physically stored on the server and it's a virtual property that is computed every time you query it but I think that's not the case here.

What you want is `Identity` ex:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

You can read more about the options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Identity is for numeric keys, i want a string-typed key

Comment: @DotnetProg: Identity doesn't care what the data type (int or string). It will use the default value sql to calculate the key in either case.

Comment: My problem is that Identity ignores the default value provided, that's the whole point of this thread...

Comment: @DotnetProg So you're explicitly setting a key that is different than the database generated value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set StoreGeneratedPattern value to Identity. I am using Database First approach and setting this property helped me a lot.

Comment: Identity is for numeric keys, i want a string-typed key

Comment: `[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string FooId { get; set; }`


I found this solution on that link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32983614/3678882

Comment: That would've worked if I entered the key in advance. I want the key to use the default value function I provided.