# Datatype declaration in Entity framework for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Could someone please tell me if this is correct?
While using entity framework in C#, every table in the database must have 1 column of datatype INT, and it must be a primary key to access the data.

I have a column of datatype float in the table. Is the above condition mandatory? Do I compulsorily have to change the data type of the column to access it using the framework? or there are other ways to do it using entity frame work.

If yes, could you please provide me with a link to refer the same for development.

Thank you

Comment: In Entity frameworks you don't have to have INT data type in your primary key. It can be of any data type you like  as long as it is set to not null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use String property as primary key in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983524/how-to-use-string-property-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @TharushaShehan - "of any data type" ? I wouldn't recommend FLOAT for keys.

Comment: Dear @HenkHolterman yes it is not good practice at all to use float, but there is no restrictions just to use INT and INT only, that what I'm highlighting there. Sorry If I have offended any community standards here by above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Read [This site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) to get a total knowledge about entity frameworks in .Net.

First two versions of Entity Framework came as a feature of .Net framework. but now Microsoft is offering it as a whole other framework.

As for the answer of above question you can use any data type as a primary key as long as that field is not null. It doesn't have to be `int` all the time. You can make it as a String if you like by stopping auto increment.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string YourId { get; set; }
```

and making the next primary key using internal code logic. In Entity frameworks there is `DB-first` and `code-first` approach. This can vary depending on your approach.

Comment: For the upvoter: all this answer says is _"you can use any data type as a primary key as long as that field is not null. it doesn't have to be INT all the time"_, without sources or explanation. The rest is noise.

Comment: Dear @CodeCaster Please note my edited answer. and thank on your feedback on this. it is really helpful and led me to the above answer.

Comment: Yeah it's better now, but the first two paragraphs still are irrelevant.