# How to edit a single object CRUD using a string as primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm making an CRUD application and I'm trying to edit a single instance of an object through the view and save the changes to the database. I'm using Entity Framework together with an repository pattern. The problem I'm having is that the primary key of my object is a string and not an int.

So the path URL i'm trying to reach when editing an customer looks like:
*/devices/editSingle/wefs3-amr3x-ngte3*

I'm using this exact same code for another object that has an int as Id and it's working properly. However I'm having a hard time refactoring this code so it's working with an string as primary key instead. When I run this code, it's running without issues when I click the editSingle for a customer button I got to the `NotFound()` page. So I assume something is wrong with my `GetByBranchId` method

**Customers Model**

```
[Key]
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string BranchId { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("name")]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
private readonly ICustomersRepository _customersRepository;

public CustomersController(DbContext dbContext, ICustomersRepository customersRepository)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _customersRepository = customersRepository;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> EditSingle(string branchId)
{
    if (branchId == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var customers = await _customersRepository.GetByBranchId(branchId);
    if (customers == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(customers);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSingle(string branchid, Customers customers)
{
    if (branchid != customers.BranchId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Here all the fields that should get updated can be stated
            _dbContext.Entry(customers).Property(p => p.CustomerName).IsModified = true;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CustomerExists(customers.BranchId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    return View(customers);
}

private bool CustomerExists(string branchid)
{
    return _dbContext.Customers.Any(e => e.BranchId == branchid);
}
```

This method is working fine when looking for an Id that's an `int`. When looking for a `string` however it seems to not function properly

**Repository**

```
public async Task<Customers> GetByBranchId(string branchId)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<Customers>().FindAsync(branchId);
}
```

**EDIT**

I managed to fix it, it was a problem in my view, i didn't specify the correct attribute in my `asp-route`

Old one

```
<td><a asp-action="EditSingle" asp-route-Id="@customer.BranchId">Edit</a></td>
```

Fix

```
<td><a asp-action="EditSingle" asp-route-branchId="@customer.BranchId">Edit</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Customers existCustomer=null;
try
        {
          
 existCustomer= await _dbContext.Set<Customers>()
                                    .Where( i=> i.branchId==branchId)
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
         if(existCustomer==null) ....return error
           existCustomer.CustomerName = customers.CustomerName;
            _dbContext.Entry(existCustomer).Property(p => p.CustomerName).IsModified =true;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
           if(existCustomer==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I've already managed to fix the issue. There was an issue with my asp-route. I'm not sure how I can close my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is related to: [How to use String property as primary key in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983524/how-to-use-string-property-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework).

Similar situation in which your primary key is a `string` and not an `int`. I'm also assuming that the function `GetByBranchId` does not work either because of the same reason (searching for an `int` with a `string`).

EDIT: You might find it more useful to leave the primary key alone (leave it as an *auto incrementing* int) and store the branch id in its own index.

Let me know if this helps, thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, there is no issue with the primary key being a string and it shouldn't auto-increment since i'm pulling this information from an external API. The issue i'm having is how I can use my GetBranchId to look for an Customer by a string

Comment: @Bram In that instance you can use something like `_dbContext.Set<Customers>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.branchId == branchId);`

Comment: @Bram `_dbContext.Set<Customers>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.branchId == branchId);`

Comment: Thanks alot I managed to fix it thanks to your comment. Also I forgot to change my asp-route to the branchId instead of Id.