# How to EF code first fluent API string primary key?

Tags: string, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, primary-key

I tried to make a primary key for Member entity, I don't want to use annotation, just use fluent API:

```
Member{
    public string MemberID {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

In MemberMapping

```
this.hasKey(t=>t.MemberID);
```

When update database I got this error:

```
Identity column 'MemberID' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with 
a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable
```

Comment: per default, EF wants its PK columns to be not null. since string is not a value type, it can be null. also PK's have to be of certain types I don't think string is one of. Additionally, EF will make PK's autoincrement, which doesn't match with string type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make string as primary key in entity framework!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117540/how-to-make-string-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF supports `string` as PK but you have to set explicitly that property with some value when you need to create an `Member`'s instance and save it into your DB. The only type that is [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) by default in EF is `int`. To fix your problem I think you have two options:

1. Change the `MemberID` column in your database to not be `Identity`. That should solve the problem.
2. If you want that EF do that change for you then add this configuration:

   ```
   this.hasKey(t=>t.MemberID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
   ```

   Create a new migration using the `Add-Migration` command and try to run again `Update-Database` command.

Now,if your `MemberID` column in your DB isn't `Identity` and you are trying to set as `Identity` the `MemberID` PK property in your model, that also could be the cause of your issue. If that is the case, remove that configuration and try to run again `Update-Database` command.

From [Programming Entity Framework Code First](https://books.google.com/books?id=ENaambUXoSAC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA46&dq=hasdatabasegeneratedoption%20entity%20framework&source=bl&ots=n3gScwaWc9&sig=V7Lce8FaU8YCVckkMXShDBfl4Cw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwjWo7TmjODIAhXCmR4KHTYtDDI#v=onepage&q=hasdatabasegeneratedoption%20entity%20framework&f=false) book, page 44:

> In the case where the Key field is an `Integer`, Code First defaults to
>   `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. With a `Guid`, you need to explicitly
>   configure this. **These are the only types that you can configure to be
>   `Identity` when Code First is generating the database**.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not the PK but the indentity. You should have something like

```
property(x => x.MemberID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(
    DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```